# How to align an epigraph?

Tags: vertical-alignment, positioning, memoir, epigraphs

I have the following code

```
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.425\textwidth}\epigraph{quote 1}{\textit{1}}

\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.425\textwidth}\epigraph{quote 2}{\textit{2}}

\lipsum
```

Which gives me the following result:
[image]

What I want to do is either have the two quotes vertically aligned (as in, one in the left and one in the right) or have the text fill the blank space left of the quotes. Is there any option?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: What should be the vertical alignment in case the two quotes have different length?

Comment: If the epigraphs should be placed one above the other, and inset into the top of the text, it might be possible to put both of them into the same `minipage` and use `wrapfig` to insert that at the beginning of the first paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

You can set both `\epigraph`s inside their own `minipage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
  \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.8\linewidth}\epigraph{quote 1}{\textit{1}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
  \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.8\linewidth}\epigraph{quote 2}{\textit{2}}
\end{minipage}

\noindent\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: You lose the setting of `\@afterheading`…

Answer (score 2):

I thank Werner for his answer and I want to add a bit more. By default epigraphs are set flushright. I think that if you want them to be set on the same line then the positioning is probably best being symetrical. That is, in the minipages both being set centered or flushleft in the first (left hand) minipage and flushright in the second (right hand) minipage.

The following minor modification to Werner's code sets the left hand epigraph flush left, while the right hand epigraph is in its default location.

```
% epigraphprob.tex  SE 619543

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
  \renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{flushleft}
  \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.8\linewidth}\epigraph{quote 1}{\textit{1}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
  \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.8\linewidth}\epigraph{quote 2}{\textit{2}}
\end{minipage}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

To center epigraphs use `\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{center}`

Answer (score 1):

I'd define a specific command.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph,xpatch}

\epigraphnoindent

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doubleepigraph}[4]{%
  \vspace{\beforeepigraphskip}
  \vbox{%
    \xpatchcmd{\@epitext}{{minipage}}{{minipage}[t]}{}{}%
    \epigraphsize
    \begin{\epigraphflush}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\epigraphwidth}
      \@epitext{#1}\\
      \@episource{#2}%
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\epigraphwidth}
      \@epitext{#3}\\
      \@episource{#4}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{\epigraphflush}%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip
  \vspace*{\afterepigraphskip}%
  \ifepigraphnoindent\@afterheading\fi
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.45\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\doubleepigraph
  {So long, and thanks for all the fish!}
  {Dolphins}
  {Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita \\
   mi ritrovai per una selva oscura \\
   che la diritta via era smarrita}
  {Dante}

Some text for the chapter.

\end{document}
```

[image]

For bottom alignment, some adjustments have to be done, which shows another reason for a specific command.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph,xpatch}

\epigraphnoindent

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doubleepigraph}[4]{%
  \vspace{\beforeepigraphskip}
  \vbox{%
    \xpatchcmd{\@epitext}{{minipage}}{{minipage}[t]}{}{}%
    \epigraphsize
    \begin{\epigraphflush}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\epigraphwidth}
      \@epitext{#1}\\
      \@episource{#2\strut}%
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\epigraphwidth}
      \@epitext{#3}\\
      \@episource{#4\strut}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{\epigraphflush}%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip
  \vspace*{\afterepigraphskip}%
  \ifepigraphnoindent\@afterheading\fi
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.45\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\doubleepigraph
  {So long, and thanks for all the fish!}
  {Dolphins}
  {Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita \\
   mi ritrovai per una selva oscura \\
   che la diritta via era smarrita}
  {Dante}

Some text for the chapter.

\end{document}
```

[image]